# unixODBC Amazon Redshift issue (Can't open lib '/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so' : file not found)

Tags: amazon-redshift, unixodbc

I am trying to set up unixODBC to access Amazon Redshift and I keep getting this error, I have triple checked my setup but not sure what the issue is

```
> isql -v mlaws
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

Below are my `.odbc.ini` and `odbcinst.ini` files and details

my current `odbcinst -j` setting is,

```
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/fuxi/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

my `odbcinst.ini` file has the appropriate Redshift Driver,

```
[PostgreSQL ANSI]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC driver (ANSI version)
Driver=psqlodbca.so
Setup=libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug=0
CommLog=1
UsageCount=1

[PostgreSQL Unicode]
Description=PostgreSQL ODBC driver (Unicode version)
Driver=psqlodbcw.so
Setup=libodbcpsqlS.so
Debug=0
CommLog=1
UsageCount=1

[Amazon Redshift (x64)]
Description=Amazon Redshift ODBC Driver(64-bit)
Driver=/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/lib/64/libamazonredshiftodbc64.so
```

I have verified the driver location.

My `.odbc.inc` is,

```
[personal]
Driver      = PostgreSQL Unicode
ServerName  = ---.---.---.---
Port        = 5432
Database    = db1
Username    = uuuuuu
Password    = xxxxxx
Debug       = 1


[mlaws]
Driver      = Amazon Redshift (x64)
ServerName  = <link>
Port        = 5439
Database    = db
Username    = uuuuuu
Password    = xxxxxx
```

I have copied my `amazon.redshiftodbc.ini` file to `/etc/` and added the following to it

```
[Driver]
## - DriverManagerEncoding is detected automatically.
##   Add DriverManagerEncoding entry if there is a need to specify.
DriverManagerEncoding = UTF-16
ErrorMessagesPath=/opt/amazon/redshiftodbc/ErrorMessages
LogLevel=0
LogPath=[LogPath]
SwapFilePath=/tmp
ODBCInstLib=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libodbcinst.so.1
```

Here are my current environment variables

```
export ODBCINI=~/.odbc.ini
export ODBCSYSINI=/etc
export AMAZONREDSHIFTODBCINI=/etc/amazon.redshiftodbc.ini
```

I am not really sure what I am doing wrong at this point. `ibamazonredshiftodbc64.so` exist where its suppose to, but unixODBC just can't seem to find it

Comment: Are you still having this problem?  Mine looks VERY similar to yours.

Comment: Bounty doesnt appear to be working.  I switched over to using Npgsql driver instead.  No ini files to worry about.

Comment: The issue is that alpine does not use Glibc and masl for its c++ math libraries and those are required for unixODBC.  You CAN install those libraries, just be sure, that if you installed unixODBC with NPM, you ALSO install glibc and all ITS dependencies with NPM also.  Otherwise they wont be able to see each other and you get the file not found error..

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

```
cp /etc/odbc.ini ~/.odbc.ini
cp /etc/odbcinst.ini ~/.odbcinst.ini

echo 'export ODBCINI=~/odbc.ini' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export ODBCSYSINI=~/directory' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

And then you should be able to see the driver name by running:

```
odbcinst -q -d
```